# Best way to sort Map with Values

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

```
private Map<Character, Integer> frequencies;
```

I have a `Map` with `Character` being Key and its associated `Integer` being Value.

Whats the best/fastest/efficeint way to sort by Value?

i.e Map may have
a,1
c,10
p,5
s,7
and after sorted,
it would be
a,1
p,5
s,7
c,10

I was thinking about doing it with Priority Queue and with integer but i would lose the Character value if the integer vals are duplicates

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) (beware of the top-voted answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priority queue is a decent approach - all you need to do is [get the `Entry` set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) from the map, and override a `Comparator` as the input to the queue.

```
Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
map.put('a',1);
map.put('c',10);
map.put('p',5);
map.put('2',7);
PriorityQueue<Entry<Character, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Character,Integer>>(map.size(), new Comparator<Entry<Character, Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<Character, Integer> arg0,
            Entry<Character, Integer> arg1) {
        return arg0.getValue().compareTo(arg1.getValue());
    }
});
pq.addAll(map.entrySet());
while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(pq.poll());
}
```

Will yield (as expected):

```
a=1
p=5
2=7
c=10
```

---

**Note:** Avoid using a `Set` or a `Map` with keys as the values of the map - because it will NOT handle duplicate values well.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Guava. It contains BiMap implementations which can be inversed, and then just sort on inversed map keys.

```
Map<Character, Integer> myMap = HashBiMap.create();
// put your values in myMap
Map<Integer, Character> inversed = myMap.inverse();
SortedMap<Integer, Character> sortedInversed = new TreeMap<Integer, Character>(inversed);
```

so just iterate the sortedInversed

Comment: What happens with this approach if multiple keys have the same value?